# mysql select substrings and group them by column

Tags: mysql, sql, database, substring

I am trying to divide data in one onf the tables on my MySQL database.

Column contains data like this:

```
de:"Sweatjacke*";en:"jacket*";pl:"bluza*";
de:"*";en:"*";pl:"bluza*";
fr:"*";de:"*";en:"*";pl:"dres junior*";cz:"*";
pl:"bluza";
```

And I am trying to divide all of the translations into separate columns. Already came with solution to do this by using:

```
SELECT 
SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(name, ';', 1), ';', -1) as tr1,
SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(name, ';', 2), ';', -1) as tr2,
SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(name, ';', 3), ';', -1) as tr3,
SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(name, ';', 4), ';', -1) as tr4,
SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(name, ';', 5), ';', -1) as tr5
FROM  product;
```

statement, but that results in:

```
tr1     tr2     tr3     tr4     tr5
fr:"*"  de:"*"  en:"*"  pl:"bluza*" cz:"*"
fr:"*"  de:"Sweatjacke*"    en:"jacket*"    pl:"bluza*" cz:"*"
de:"Sweatjacke*"    en:"jacket*"    pl:"bluza*"
```

And I want to have the results gruped by translation type (pl/de/en) so in each collumn one type of translatoin is present. For example in column1 = pl:*, column2 = en:* etc.

Any one came across similar problem and knows a way to solve it?

Comment: The difficulty of doing this is why you shouldn't use this table design. You need to learn about database normalization.

Comment: Tell that to the one that created this table design ;-) I am the one who is trying to fix it.

Comment: I think if you search the Internet you can find some UDF that do substring extration using regexp. There's no easy way to do it with normal MySQL functions.

Comment: SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX( SUBSTRING( name, LOCATE( "pl:", name ) , 150 ) , ';', 1 ) AS pl, SUBSTRING_INDEX( SUBSTRING( name, LOCATE( "en:", name ) , 150 ) , ';', 1 ) AS en, SUBSTRING_INDEX( SUBSTRING( name, LOCATE( "de:", name ) , 150 ) , ';', 1 ) AS de, SUBSTRING_INDEX( SUBSTRING( name, LOCATE( "fr:", name ) , 150 ) , ';', 1 ) AS fr
FROM product

Did the job ;-) thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to unpivot the data, then select the first and second part of each value and then re-aggregate it.

However, a better form for the data is really to have language/translation.  The following produces this:

```
select substring_index(tr, ':', 1) as l, substring_index(tr, ':', 2) as t, name
from (select SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(name, ';', n.n), ';', -1) as tr, n, name
      from product p cross join
           (select 1 as n union all select 2 union all select 3 union all select 4 union all
            select 5
           ) n
     ) n
```

You would probably want an "id" column or "word" column to identify each row, rather than the `name` column.

You can now pivot this result to get what you want:

```
select max(case when l = 'en' then name end) as en,
       max(case when l = 'fr' then name end) as fr,
       max(case when l = 'de' then name end) as de,
       max(case when l = 'pl' then name end) as pl,
       max(case when l = 'cz' then name end) as cz
from (select substring_index(tr, ':', 1) as l, substring_index(tr, ':', 2) as t, name
      from (select SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(name, ';', n.n), ';', -1) as tr, n, name
            from product p cross join
                 (select 1 as n union all select 2 union all select 3 union all select 4 union all
                  select 5
                 ) n
           ) n
      ) lt
group by name;
```

Comment: Thanks Gordon, but thats not the case. Manage to solve it using substrings:

Answer (score 0):

Managed to solve it by using some of the string related functions funcitons:

```
SELECT 
SUBSTRING_INDEX( SUBSTRING( name, LOCATE( "pl:", name ) , 150 ) , ';', 1 ) AS pl,
SUBSTRING_INDEX( SUBSTRING( name, LOCATE( "en:", name ) , 150 ) , ';', 1 ) AS en, 
SUBSTRING_INDEX( SUBSTRING( name, LOCATE( "de:", name ) , 150 ) , ';', 1 ) AS de, 
SUBSTRING_INDEX( SUBSTRING( name, LOCATE( "fr:", name ) , 150 ) , ';', 1 ) AS fr
FROM product
```

Thanks to everyone for help.

Comment: This works as long as you can hard-code the list of languages in your query.

Answer (score -1):

As far as I understand you want to UNPIVOT your data. There is no such function in MySQL, so you might want to export your data into MSSQL (you can use free MSSQL Express) and use UNPIVOT function: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: Thx IgorM, but its not about pivoting/unpivoting. I want to split the columns. But split it not only by using ';' separator but also assign the data into correct colums.